# Script/Workflow: Select item, print, save as PDF, name sequentially, down arrow to next item

Tags: applescript, automator, pdf, printing, serial-number

Yet again I have a task to do that would be great to automate. Yet after searching for examples that are even close I am nowhere.

Here is what I am trying to do:
First I Perform a search by specific year (Only needs to be done once so I can do this manually) Then I select the first record to get things set to run a loop routing. Next will be the repeated actions;

1. depress COMMAND + SHIFT + P to print
2. depress my own defined keyboard shortcut "^P" that's tied to an
   automator script which then performs a "Save As PDF..."
3. depress right arrow to move to the end of the generic name
4. paste the next highest number
5. depress the "Save" button (Enter/Return Key press)...which puts me
   back into the main window where I need to:
6. depress the down arrow key then go to step "1."

I can not use AppleScript because the database application is not supported and there isn't a dictionary I can open with supported AppleScript definitions.

Seems like Automator would work but really have no clue about Automator and to be honest every time I try and use it I end up spinning my wheels for days then eventually give up because I just need to get the work done.

Comment: Complicated ? do you want to convert bunch of files (or specific text with in the file) to PDF ? and do that automatically as a new file is added to a folder ?

Comment: Buscar if it were just converting to PDF that would be very simple and easy to find a ton of ready made scripts that I could use which I would be happy to do. What I want done is the automation of the keystrokes that are depressed (to PRINT then NAME then SAVE and DOWN ARROW to next record). So maybe it is a macro program but how to serialize/increment the numbers of the filenames?

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded Keyboard Maestro and was able to get what I needed by writing a macro. I have a new favorite program. I kind of wish I had tried it sooner.